# JPA avoid loading Objects before Insert

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

Person has a foreign key of the field "Language". How can I avoid loading the whole "Language" object if I just got the PK of a language ("json.get("language").asInt()) and want to insert a new Person?

```
@Entity
public class Person {
   String prename;
   String lastname;
   Language language;
}


Person p = new Person("Robert", "Meyer");
Language l = JPA.em().find(Language.class, json.get("language").asInt();
p.setLanguage(l);
```

Is it possible to do it in a way without having to load the whole Language object?

Comment: If your DB has a foreign key constraint, you need first save related entity. Or you can perform check if such related entity exists in DB, e. g. using native query.

Comment: does your Language object exist before you create a new Person ?

Comment: yes, the Language objects exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [EntityManager#getReference()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getReference(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object)).

> Get an instance, whose state may be lazily fetched. If the requested instance does not exist in the database, the EntityNotFoundException is thrown when the instance state is first accessed.

```
Person p = new Person("Robert", "Meyer");
Language l = JPA.em().getReference(Language.class, json.get("language").asInt();
p.setLanguage(l);
```